# ConstraintLayout button in centre and size as 1/3 of ViewPager

Tags: android, button, android-constraintlayout

I'm using the ConstraintLayout and I want to display button in the centre of ViewPager but with width and height of 1/3 of this pager.I used horizontal and vertical chain. And got the next:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/send_button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/view_pager"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button2" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/view_pager"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button2"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/view_pager"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button2"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button4"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button5"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button1"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button3" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/button2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/view_pager" />

<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/vertical_guideline"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/basic_keyline"
    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/basic_keyline"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/basic_keyline"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="@string/send"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/vertical_guideline"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />
```

But I think this approach is so scary. Maybe somebody know better solution, please help me. I want to use only xml without using the code.

UPDATE

[image]

Buttons were added to easy understand what I want.

Comment: The layout you posted has multiple `<Button>` tags, but your question seems to refer to only a single `Button`. Could you perhaps include an image of what you'd like the layout to look like? Or clarify what the purpose of these extra Buttons are?

Comment: can you please share screenshot for your layout so I can understand easily.

Comment: @BenP. I updated my question with screenshot.

Comment: @MehulKabaria I updated my question

Comment: @RuslanLeshchenko : Share your layout which you want?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan sure if you can.

Comment: sorry mistake in comment not asking you.Could you include an image of what you'd like the layout to look like?

Comment: @ShwetaChauhan I want to get the same layout as I posted but if it is possible, without using chain.

Comment: Best way even than the below answer is to set `toptoTop, bottomtoBottom, lefttoLeft ans righttoRight` to viewpager and use percent dimensions feature of constraint layout and give 33.3% width and height. This way you will have to use least widgets and will provide the best output in any screen size. Sorry can't post answer as from app now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what you can do without adding so many buttons and also without guidelines.

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"    
    android:id="@+id/apbLay1"
    tools:context="studios.brilliant.com.commutech.Home">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_marginBottom="152dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
       />    
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_percent=".333"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="percent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent=".333"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        />      
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>    
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This will give you the exact output you need and you're getting as in the screenshot provided.

[image]
.333 is 33.3% of the parent which is almost equal to 1/3.

That extra layout is to add a container for the viewpager and button as using viewpager as the container can cause the button to hide when the fragment will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a `ConstraintLayout` into your `PageViewer` so that you can use `GuideLines` to constraint the `Button`.

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/send_button"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/left_guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/right_guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/top_guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.33" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/bottom_guideline"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.67" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/top_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/left_guideline"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/right_guideline" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```